# Best approach for real time operating system on Raspberry Pi

Tags: kernel, real-time

I need to use Raspberry Pi with a real time operating system. Of course, I want the best solution. I've searched some options, including custom kernel compilation, ready to install RTOS.

So, which will be the better approach? I couldn't find for a good article about it.

Best regards.

Comment: That may depend on why you need a real time operating system.  What do you plan to use it for?

Comment: Automation. The Raspberry will be connected to couple of PLCs to manager their behavior.

Comment: Then you likely doesn't need real time. The PLCs will take care of the true real time parts. Standard Linux will suffice just fine.

Comment: I kinda agree with you. But let's say that the scenario can't accept errors. The raspberry must receive data from internet, control the PLCs and the system can't never freeze. So I'll add this layer of security with a real time Linux running the RPi.

Comment: The real-time distributions may be more likely to freeze.  They may have received a lot less testing than a main stream distribution.

Comment: Well, you still don't need real time. It will work with standard Linux, which never freeze. That's why embedded Linux is preferred over embedded Windows. However, there are several Linux distributions adapted for embedded use, where the overhead applications has been removed. Please have a look at may project Nard SDK http://www.arbetsmyra.dyndns.org/nard/ but there are others too.

Comment: There's a port of FreeRTOS for the Raspberry Pi: https://github.com/jameswalmsley/RaspberryPi-FreeRTOS

Comment: I just saw that *NARD SDK* is your own project, @ronny-nilson. :)
The latest version has a more than one year old. What happened to the project?